# How to get an overview of all branches ahead of remote branch in TortoiseGit?

Tags: tortoisegit

I often commit to local branches and switch between them without pushing the commits to the remote branches right away. From time to time I want to review *all* commits which are ahead of the respective remote branches. Based on this I want to push some of the branches to remote.

Particularly I would like to get an overview with TortoiseGit of all branches which are ahead of their remote branches in one list.

I have been used to the overview in SourceTree where all branches with pending commits where highlighted:

[image: screenshot of how branches which deviate from the remote are highlighted]

I am searching for a similar feature in TortoiseGit.

I have tried the Sync Dialog: As far as I understand I can only see the outgoing commits of *one branch at a time*. The solution would be acceptable if this list contains the incoming commits as well (distinguishable).

Is there a way to get a list with *all* branches where outgoing commits are pending? I also want to use this feature in order to check if I forgot to push any commits.

I have seen the "Push all branches" option in the push dialog. This is not what I am searching for as I need to review the commits before pushing them.

Comment: Have you checked the Sync Dialog? When you fetch you will see all differences to the remote tracked branches.

Comment: @MrTux, can you please add some details, how this can be used to hightlight the branches which are ahead of remote? I have seen the following in the Sync Dialog: When fetching all references the branches and tags are listed in the "Ref List" tab. One can also filter references with changes which have not been applied locally. Unfortunately I don't see how I can highlight or filter references which have outgoing commits (those changes are already applied to the local clone).  
In the tab "In Commits" and "Out Commits" I only find the commits respective to the selected branch, not all branches.

Comment: Looks like it's related to the [TortoiseGit issue 2296](https://gitlab.com/tortoisegit/tortoisegit/issues/2296)

Comment: @YueLinHo: As far as I understand [TortoiseGit issue 2296](https://gitlab.com/tortoisegit/tortoisegit/issues/2296) is about monitoring incoming commits from the remote repository. My question is about outgoing commits (from the local clone to the remote repository). My intention is to be aware of all the commits which are local only (thus pending) of _all_ branches. I want to make sure I don't forget to push anything important.

Answer (score -1):

Just want to clarify your question:

**Does the following figure match the figure you provided?**

[image]

Comment: The above figure matches the intended changes within branches. The feature I am looking for would show only the branches which divert from the known origin repository. More precisely I am looking for the list of branches with outgoing commits.

Comment: The general log is not what I am looking for as _all_ commits are listed. Thus branches with pending commits may be far below in the list and therefore hidden. Does this clarify my question for you @Yue?

Comment: @user5534993 Yes. Thank you. :)